# Byte I/O with DMA, what's the advantage?

Tags: embedded, dma, firmware

I have a A/D where signals CPU whenever it has new sample, and CPU reads that through a SPI, which is few bytes.

My question is, can we use DMA here? Who and how should tell DMA to transfer new data?

Does it make sense to use DMA? This is basically like an interrupt I/O. Everytime A/D signals new sample, main software tells DMA to transfer it. So there is no improvement in efficiency. main is still involved continuously in I/O.

Comment: What kind of hardware?

Answer (score 1):

If you are transferring one sample per interrupt, DMA is not going to give you much of a performance gain. DMA helps more on blocks of data.